# Calling a variable from a function in a function

Tags: python, function, variables

Quick question. I first defined a function **prc_chgd** that ultimately gives me a variable **ans**, but as an intermediate step gives me the variable **price**.
Now, I want to write a subsequent function **hdg**, that using the same order of inputs, used the intermediate variable **price** to calculate something else. Unfortunately, I don't know how :S

```
def prc_chgd(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y):
    price = xyz
    ans   = price*abc

def hedge(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y):
    from prc_chgd(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y) import price
    ans = price*xxxx
```

the point is that the functions are two separate excercises within a notebook assignment, and I might have to recalculate the preceding function with new inputs (in the same order though), and only choose the defined variable **price** for my calculation.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Where is `hedge` called from? You'll need to return `price` from `prc_chgd` if you want it to be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot completely follow, but I think your `xyz` is some mysterial combination of `p0, ta, ya` etc.

In this case, you should put the price calculation into a separate function such as

```
def calc_price(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y):
    return xyz # calculated with these inputs

def prc_chgd(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y):
    price = calc_price(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y)
    ans = price * abc

def hedge(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y):
    price = calc_price(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y)
    ans = price * xxxx
```

If you want to avoid to have your `price` be computed twice, you could also do

```
def calc_price(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y):
    return xyz # calculated with these inputs

def prc_chgd(price):
    ans = price * abc

def hedge(price):
    ans = price * xxxx
```

and leave it to the caller how often `calc_price()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can return more than one value from your function if you want like this:

```
def prc_chgd(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y):
    price = xyz
    ans   = price*abc
    return price, ans


def hedge(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y):
    price, ans = prc_chgd(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y)
    ans = price*xxxx
```

Comment: looks good in theory, but in my assignment the first function is evaluated on the output of prc_chgd, and will only take one value. thus, if I return two values in the function body, I get an error message from my assignment saying it expects only one value as output.

Answer (score -1):

Function that returns multiple return values should yield in python:

```
def prc_chgd(p0, ta, ya, tb, yb, cb, delta1_y, delta2_y):
   price = xyz
   yield price
   ans   = price*abc
   yield ans
```

You can yield as many values as you like. 
Then you can iterate over all the answers in a for loop:

```
for total in prc_chgd(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8):
   print total
```

First it will print the price, then price*abs. Since the 2 functions belong together, I recommend to use a class.